# Difference between >> and >>> in Scala

Tags: scala, operators, bit-shift

Is there any difference between >> and >>> operator in Scala?

```
scala> 0x7f >>> 1
res10: Int = 63

scala> 0x7f >> 1 
res11: Int = 63

scala> 0x7f >> 4
res12: Int = 7

scala> 0x7f >>> 4
res13: Int = 7
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `>>` operator preserves the sign (sign-extends), while `>>>` zeroes the leftmost bits (zero-extends).

```
-10>>2
res0: Int = -3
-10>>>2
res1: Int = 1073741821
```

[Try it out yourself.](http://www.simplyscala.com/)

This is not necessary in languages like C which has signed and unsigned types, unlike Java, which also has `>>>` (because it has no unsigned integers).

Comment: [Where is simplyscala gone?](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/3didyu/where_is_simplyscala_gone/)

Comment: Try Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ICn3wtc5TlSIpw5OBlR7Qw

Answer (score 5):

They have the same meaning as in Java.

From [The Java™ Tutorials - Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

> The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left, and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position, while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

---

`>>>` only exists in Java, but not C or C++.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Int.scala#L73

Answer (score 2):

Note: with [SLIP 30](https://github.com/scala/slip/pull/30) (Nov. 2015), Scala might end up (in 2016? 2017?) with 4 "primitive" types to represent unsigned integers: `UByte`, `UShort`, `UInt` and `ULong`.

That would impact [Bit shifting operations on UInts and ULongs](https://github.com/sjrd/slip/blob/uints/text/0000-unsigned-integers.md#bit-shifting-operations-on-uints-and-ulongs), which also illustrates the difference between `>>` and `>>>`:

> Shift left `<<` and shift logical right `>>>` behave in the obvious way.
>
> The case of shift arithmetic right `>>` is debatable.
>   We argue that it should not be available on unsigned integers for two reasons:
>
> - First, a shift arithmetic right does not appear to have any meaning on unsigned integers. The correct arithmetic shift if `>>>`. Therefore, similarly to `unary_-`, it should not be introduced.
> - Second, **existing languages that do have unsigned integer types, such as the C family, actually give different semantics to `>>` depending on whether it has a signed or unsigned operand**:
>     A `>>` on an unsigned operand does not sign-extend. It would be confusing to a C developer for `x >> 3` to sign-extend in Scala, but it would be equally confusing to a Scala developer that `x >> 3` not sign-extend. Therefore, we prefer to leave it out completely, and let a compiler error be raised.
>
> If a bit-twiddling-based algorithm needs the sign-extending shift right, it is always possible to reinterpret as signed, do the operation, and reinterpret back as unsigned: `(x.toInt >> 3).toUInt`.
>
> Note: the current implementation does provide `>>`, until we agree on this point.